# creation of domain based on date odoo v8

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I'm using odoo v8 and 
I've been trying to create a domain on a field many2one based on date`

```
date_now=fields.Date(default=datetime.now())
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
lot=fields.Many2one('stock.production.lot','lot',domain[('life_date','>=',datetime.strptime(str(datetime.now()), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))])
```

I've been trying a lot of combinations but none seems to work !

can any one please show me the correct way to create a domain where i can compare life_date and current date (or date_now )

thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i finally made it 
there is a function called 
def on_change_product() 
inside it i put

date_now=None       
`if not date_now: 
date_now = fields.Date.today()`

```
res['domain'] = {'lot': [('product_id', '=', prod.id),
                     ('life_date', '>', date_now)]}
```

Answer (score 1):

use attribute

```
domain=[(your domain filter)]
```

in the field definition that will do for you.

Comment: yea sure thats what im trying to do 
domain = [('life_date','>=',datetime.strptime(str(datetime.now()), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))])
but i got errors like :
datetime.strptime(str(datetime.now()), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))])
odoo    |   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 328, in _strptime
odoo    |     data_string[found.end():])
odoo    | ValueError: unconverted data remains: .764757

Comment: simply use datetime object in the domain filter do not convert it to string.

Comment: thnx for the quick replies by the way =) ,, when i dnt convert it , i got erro that my object should be string
may be if you write to me what should i write on the domain would help me alot .. im not sure if we are writing domain same way .

Comment: Welcome.... consider accepting and or upvoting it, that's the way we say thank you on stack overflow :) for quick replies.

Comment: you can either call a function from domain filter and then return data in [('field','=',result)] form

Comment: i guess i cnt vote , cause im beginner here :! :/ for the domain im not sure how to do that ! would you please show the right way ? i've been improvising a lot and none worked i wan to show only lot that life_date > date now !?